# HTAccess - Confusing clean url's

Tags: mysql, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If i wanted to simply redirect `/clients/page/` to `/clients.php?view=page` i would use something as simple as this, it works great.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^clients/([^/]+) /clients.php?section=$1&$2 [NC]
```

If i had for example, a url like: `/clients/page/?name=Tom` how could i transfer those HTTP GET variables to a simple url like `/clients.php?view=page&name=Tom` i have tried and failed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [QSA] flag, which stands for Query String Append. This means that you can add variables to the Query String easily:

```
RewriteRule ^clients/([^/]+) /clients.php?section=$1 [QSA, NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [QSA] flag on the RewriteRule:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule

That should cause mod_rewrite to preserve your original query parameters.

```
RewriteRule ^clients/([^/]+) /clients.php?section=$1 [QSA,NC]
```