# Rewrite query string "?x=y" style to "/x/y" style

Tags: apache, model-view-controller, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I have a PHP MVC framework I've built from scratch which uses the traditional `domain.com/controller/action` URL routing. While I'm currently handling the below conversion in the router I'd like to replace them in the URL for cosmetic reasons.

For example:

```
controller/action?filter=bank
```

Becomes:

```
controller/action/filter/bank
```

I've done a bit of experimentation with a regex but can't seem to find a match. I'm also not sure how to rewrite it using `RewriteCond`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen how IPS does this in their IP.Board product? If you have access to an IPB ftp, then check out their code for doing this. They don't use .htaccess for it also.

Comment: Does my answer help? Do you need something additional?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at some of the questions on [clean-urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clean-urls), [mod-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) and [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess).

[HTAccess - Confusing clean url's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088804/htaccess-confusing-clean-urls/2088854)

[Getting two variables in the URL with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569725/getting-two-variables-in-the-url-with-htaccess/2569734)

[Needs some help with an apache mod-rewrite issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549408/needs-some-help-with-an-apache-mod-rewrite-issue/2549688)

Answer (score 0):

The Zend Framework URL format is nearly identical to this, and [here's what they use](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.rewrite.html#project-structure.rewrite.apache.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

If your server-side script is PHP, you could use this to grab the url parts:

```
$request_parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$controller = $request_parts[0];
$action = $request_parts[1];
// etc...
```

Comment: That redirects everything to index.php, which is what I am doing. What I'm looking for is a way to reformat the URL after it has been sent by a GET form, creating the "?x==y&z=1" style. I'm thinking this may be doable in a PHP config.

Comment: I understand the reasons to make internal URLs clean, but it seems odd to do a redirect on a `GET` request simply to clean up the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your response to my other answer, I propose that you use JavaScript to handle the filter form submit and create the "clean url" request on the client side.

---

**EDIT**

I recently implemented this on my Year/Month picker for my calendar application.  It uses jQuery/JavaScript to detect changes in the form and write the "clean" URL:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.jumpform select').change(function() {
        $form = $(this).closest('form');
        window.location = $form.attr('action')
                + '/y/' + encodeURIComponent($form.find('select[name="y"]').val())
                + '/m/' + encodeURIComponent($form.find('select[name="m"]').val());
    });
});
```