# How to create URLs like www.example.com/EN/login

Tags: php, url

I want to add multiple languages to my website in the way that I would like something like http://www.example.com/EN/login for English and http://www.example.com/DE/anmelden for German. Both of the URLs should pass the requests to http://www.example.com/login.php.

Now I am wondering in general how would you create a URL like that, do I need a file `anmelden.php` inside the `DE` directory? Or does the directory `DE/anmelden` not exist and its all done with `.htaccess`? And how can I extract the "DE" and "anmelden"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htacces to create friendly URLs. Help needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you are using PHP, you will want to use a .htaccess file to do your URL rewriting. Check out this [beginner's guide](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) to mod_rewrite.

This is the example they use, which rewrites from index.php?page=software to /page/software:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

The EN/DE can be achieved through htaccess and passed to a script. You can extract the URL by using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'];` from that script and output/forward the proper view

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to do it with htaccess, because I dont really know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/
This will help you allot not in languages but in other functionality too