# How to rewrite a dynamic URL?

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htacces to create friendly URLs. Help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed)

I need help on understanding how to display a pretty URL for a URL with dynamic parameters.

In my website, when you click on the product link it will take you to the page with this url: http://example.com/products?id=1002

How can it be changed to display http://example.com/products/1002?

Comment: By changing the output. Also use the search on this website, we had that question a few times already. You might see yours downvoted because of that.

Comment: Did you read [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/intro.html) It is the minimum reading before attempting to use URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: change your pages so that the product links that you generate look like this: `http://example.com/products/1002`. You control this content, you can generate your links to look like anything you want. If you're using some kind of framework, it may even have a built in mechanism for doing this.

Step 2: add this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/(.+?)/?$ /products/?id=$1 [L]
```