# manage friendly URL's with get method and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I'm trying to create a friendly url manager with PHP.

My problem is, I have this URL:

```
mywebsite.com/page.php?var1=value1&var2=value2.....etc
```

How I can get same info in this way:

```
mywebsite.com/page/var1/value1/var2/value2
```

var1,var2,etc.. are dinamically vars they can have other dynamic names

thanks for help!

Comment: `var1/value1/var2/value2` is the same ugly url. Provide a real life example

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htacces to create friendly URLs. Help needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand what do you need it, but here we go..:

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

php:

```
$vars = array();
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])):
    $tmp = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    for ($n=0;$n<count($tmp);$n++):
        $vars[$tmp[$n]] = (isset($tmp[$n+1]))?$tmp[$n+1]:NULL;
        $n++;
    endfor;
endif;
```

You got :

```
 yourlink.com/var1/value1/var2/value2
 $var[value1] = value1
 $var[value2] = value2
```