# WordPress like .htacces nice urls

Tags: .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htacces to create friendly URLs. Help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed)

I want to build a script like WordPress for the "nice urls", i copied the .htaccess rows and made some modifications, but on the side of the PHP i don't know how to build it.

I don't understand how it works.

Comment: i went to the link you provided, but i don't understand how to do that on the PHP side...

Comment: have a look at the accepted answer.

Comment: ok i understand but i want to know how WordPress script works...

Comment: http://xref.wordpress.org/trunk/

Comment: i know that way too, but i don't know which class or function is it...

Comment: never mind, i found it: WP_Rewrite

thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Daniel A White i found the class in WordPress files.

WP_Rewrite: http://xref.wordpress.org/trunk/WordPress/Rewrite/WP_Rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Start with setting rewrite engine and follow sym links

```
RewriteEngine On

# Drop the .php --  or any other extension you use.
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#Forces the site to switch to www.site.com - change the site/TDL below
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^insuranceiwant\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.insuranceiwant.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now name your pages something useful like   site.com/contact-us
If you are pulling dynamic pages from a database, also add this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_]+)_([A-Z]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ /Resources/city.php?state=$1&region=$2&city=$3
```

That example shows that the dynamic page has a state name, state abbreviation, and a city pulling from the database and showing the page like so:
    insuranceiwant.com/California_CA/Los_Angeles

For more information on regular expresion for your page names check out this useful site:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/