# How to create a directory with a single file in it?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I'll be signing businesses up to advertise on my website, and I want them to have a direct URL for their customers to go to.

Like, instead of `www.website.com/page.php?id=324234234`,

I want to have `www.website.com/businessname`

Is there a simple way to do this? I've searched and seen a whole bunch of different things people are trying to do but I haven't seen anything that's the same as what I want to do.

I'm using a VPS, and I want to make sure that I don't open up permissions so that anyone can get in there and mess things up.

Also, these users will not be signing themselves up. I will be doing that.

The simplest way to get my end result is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're using apache this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-iterating what jtheman said with a little more explanation:

Create a file named .htaccess with the contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?businessname=$1 [L]
```

You need, of course, the ability to have directory level .htaccess enabled - you're using a VPS so you should be able to do this if it is not already enabled.

So let me explain what each line will do.

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Turns on the ability to URL re-write

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Tells Apache not to re-direct files that exist in the directory already

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?businessname=$1 [L]
```

This is where the magic happens.

`^(.*)$` this part is like a regular expression match. It will tell Apache to collect any URLs that have any characters within them and redirect them to page.php?businessname=(.*)

So, if you post:
`www.website.com/stackover`

It will really be sending: `www.website.com/page.php?businessname=stackover`

Then you can just use `$_GET[businessname]` to dynamically update the page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... No need for me to elaborate my answer then...  +1

Answer (score 5):

Basic URL rewriting could work.

Add to your .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?businessname=$1 [L]
```

Then use PHP to rewrite the businessname to the ID of the company / find the data.

Of course .htaccess rewrite rules is a complete science if you need more complex rewriting...

Comment: @Madbreaks Not many VPS'es out there without apache... But of course all might exist...

Comment: Google: _windows vps_ :) But, you got my +1 anyway

Comment: @Madbreaks And additionally he's scripting in PHP... I don't think you would add the extra bucks for a Windows VPS and then install PHP running IIS...

Comment: @Madbreaks Thats Apache to me... :)