# How to use .htaccess for beautiful links

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htacces to create friendly URLs. Help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed)

I am using ids to display the records (profiles ) of members.

So `/profile.php?id=1` displays the data of member with id 1.

But these urls are ugly and not SEO friendly either.

I want change the urls to the format `profiles/membername` (membername is a unique alias for each member already stored in the db).

How can I achieve this link structure through .htaccess?

Comment: i want _beautiful links_ too :D

Comment: You should solve this in your application, not with `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires apache's mod_rewrite module to be installed. What you want can be achieved through the following piece of code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profiles/(.*)?$ profile.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

Example:
www.yourwebsite.com/profiles/1234 -> www.yourwebsitename.com/profile.php?id=1234
If you want more variables just modify the above line like below:

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/(.*)/(.*)?$ profile.php?id=$1&var2=$2
```

Just edit your .htaccess file and add the above lines, make sure you create a backup of your .htaccess before making any modifications.

Comment: Thanks Sathiya but what if there are thousands of potential id's so do I have to create the rule for each of them?

Comment: Not really, the single rule above acts as a wild card entry:
RewriteRule ^profiles/(.*)?$ profile.php?id=$1

That means its valid for all URL's of the form /profiles/1234 or /profiles/1235 etc, wherein the '1234' and '1235' are values for the ID variable.
The second rule I posted was just an example showing you how to rewrite URL's in case you wanted to send more than one parameter i.e ?id=1234&name=John

Answer (score 1):

Firstly see some articles about problematics
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^profiles/(a-z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so e.g. `/profiles/membername` ---> `/profile.php?username=membername`

Comment: Thanks but what if there are thousands of potential id's so do I have to create the rule for each of them?

Comment: nope its universal... `/profiles/anything` --> `/profile.php?username=anything`

Comment: Thanks a lot will try this today. and let u know