# How do you do dynamic url. example.com/profile/CroatiaGM

Tags: javascript, php

I am doing the user control panel, and I have some problems I am not sure how to do this dynamic profile link currently. example.com/profile/CroatiaGM What would be the best way to go about this, My site is mainly PHP, is it better to use js or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking to rewrite a URL, where you'd like to rewrite example.com/profile.php?user=CroatiaGM to example.com/profile/CroatiaGM.

in such an instance I believe this would be helpful if you don't already have a .htaccess file, I suggest you create one in your main directory/public_html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1&type=$2
</IfModule>
```

or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ $1.php?username=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ $1.php?username=$2&type=$3
</IfModule>
```

Here's a working example.
https://locationtestproject.000webhostapp.com/test/myname

I strongly advise making a back of the .htaccess before saving any changes.

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-
[How to use .htaccess for beautiful links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546712/how-to-use-htaccess-for-beautiful-links)
https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works
https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: So this way i am doing is very wrong, right?
    `$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    $baseurl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";

    $pos = strrpos($url, '/');
    $profilename = $pos === false ? $url : substr($url, $pos + 1);`

if ($pos === 32) {
}

Comment: so how would you go about doing somesite.com/profile/CroatiaGM/pictures would you just go example.com/profile.php?user=CroatiaGM&pictures or ?

Comment: for simplicity sake, you'll have to do something like this example.com/profile.php?user=CroatiaGM&type=pictures

Comment: How would you do it in the .htaccess file? with example.com/profile.php?user=CroatiaGM&type=pictures

Comment: something like this.    RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ test.php?username=$1&type=$2

Comment: One more thing whats the diffrance between those two .ht files that you sent up there. Do you recommend one above other?

Comment: for the first one, the rewriting will only be applied to the profile.php file while the second approach will apply to all PHP files. I recommending using the first example since you have better control over what URL gets rewritten.

Comment: Is that first one compatible with removing php extension like this RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: I am not sure I am having difficulty getting this to work I put everything as you said but it still doesn't redirect, I am using windows 10 XAMPP I put allow overwrite on all and enabled mod-rewrite module this is my htacess file

 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ test.php?username=$1&type=$2

Comment: I tried a simple redirect to the URL and it works but this ht file that you posted above does not work for me for some reason.

Comment: This should do the trick,     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?$ $1.php
    RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1
    RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ profile.php?username=$1&type=$2
    </IfModule>

Comment: please make sure your file name is reflected in the .htaccess, change profile.php file name to your file name.

Comment: yeah, I got it working anyway I need to convert it to Nginx format but everything works now thanks.