# URL Redirection with condition

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htacces to create friendly URLs. Help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed)

I am new to url rewritting so here's my query

I have a site `http://www.mysite.com/ichat` now if a request comes like `http://www.mysite.com/ichat/a2b35'

I want to redirect it to a php file in my server in the ichat directory as under

`http://www.mysite.com/ichat/chat.php?chatid=a2b35`

but if the url is like this

`http://www.mysite.com/ichat/special/a2b35'

i want to redirect it to

`http://www.mysite.com/ichat/chat.php?special=yes&chatid=a2b35`

the chatid will be alphanumeric without special characters.  Is this redirection possible or i need a physical `special` folder for this to work?

Comment: And you couldn't find anything here on SO that relates to the topic of url rewriting?

Comment: search for url rewrites, there tons of posts about it around the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just take advantage of the fact that rewrites are ordered in evaluation:

```
RewriteRule ^/ichat/special/(.+) /chat.php?special=yes&chatid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/ichat/(.+) /chat.php?chatid=$1 [L]
```

The `[L]` means that rule evaluation will stop at the rule if it matches it, so any `/ichat/special/` url will get caught by the first rule, and the other `/ichat/` urls will get caught by the second.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. Whether you have helped or not is a different story :).

Comment: Thanks for answering... it didn't solve my problem but was a great insight on what was wrong.  Thanks once again.

Answer (score -1):

Based on above code , below is sample code when page can be redirected on ichat in url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~ichat/ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/ichat/chat.php?chatid=$1 [R,L]
```

Put the above code in .htaccess file.

May this would help you.