# Replacing URLs with .htaccess or something else?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen sites that have replaced their originally URL with something else. Example: instead of using `http://url.com/profile/index.php?username=USERNAME` they're using `http://url.com/profile/USERNAME`

How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/htacces-to-create-friendly-urls-help-needed?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(profile)/([^/.]+)/?$ /$1/index.php?username=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```