# htaccess rewrite code safety

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently learning to use htaccess and I have a question about code safety.
My PHP app starts from one entry point - index.php so I wish to rewrite the url to /index.php
I made a little research but nothing could works exactly as needed so I combined few things and created something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^((?!public).)*$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

It works as I intended, it rewrites all URLs except those starting with /public to index.php
As I am not very advanced, my question is, is such code safe? Could it be attacked some way?

Comment: Since it doesn't really "do" anything security sensitive I'd say the answer is [*Mu*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#.22Unasking.22_the_question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create friendly URLs with .htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 2):

The rewrite rules can't be "attacked" unless you've configured something wrong. As long as you *don't* want to route requests that start with `public` to `index.php` and *do* want to route everything else to `index.php`, that's all there is to it.

The actual "security" of that notion depends on the php code that you are hosting.