# Sending path and GET to index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Let me give you an example:

I open up this address using my browser: `http://localhost/AAA/BBB/CCC?id=5&foo=bar`

I want to write a `.htaccess` that implicitly converts the link to: `http://localhost/index.php?route=/AAA/BBB/CCC&id=5&foo=bar`

Whatever the destination link will be, I don't care; I just want it to contain both path, and GET request. Notice that some URL like the one below don't contain any parameter, but must be parsed correctly:
`http://localhost/AAA/BBB`
will be converted to `http://localhost/index.php?route=/AAA/BBB`

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create friendly URLs with .htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to capture whatever request url is present and append it as "route":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

A side note: if you have access to the real server configuration, then prefer that to `.htaccess` style files. Those files make things more complex, are notoriously error prone and make the server sloooooow!

Comment: It's cool, but there's a little problem and that is, if someone specifies route in GET, things get mixed up: `localhost/test?get1=5&get2=10&route=asd`

Comment: Sure, but there is nothing you can do about that. You have a name collision, rewriting cannot "fix" that. You'd have to use scripting for that. Certainly you should make sure you pick an identifier that is not used otherwise throughout your logic.