# some issue on rewriting url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

When user visit "https://www.example.com/api3/SGy7bT" url then i want to load "https://www.example.com/api3/webhook3_index2.php?random=SGy7bT" page. On the browser the url will not change and it will appear like top mentioned url.

My htaccess file is exist on "/api3" folder.

Comment: I have got the answer from "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess" url. The issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api3/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /api3/webhook3_index2\.php\?random=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILEAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILEAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webhook3_index2.php?random=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. It's working fine when visiting that url but we have other pages under "/api3" folder and when visiting other pages under "/api3" folder then always getting "404 not found". Please help me.