# Rewrite Rule for GET variables .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Well I'm havin trouble creating `.htaccess`, anyway I have categories in my menu for example `test1`,`test2`,`test3` that are the names of a folders, and what I'm trying to do is to point the second parameter of the url to `index.php`, for example `http://myapp/test1` I want to be able from the `index.php` to have `$_GET['cat'] = test1` and so on.. 

Here's what I've tried so far and didn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?cat=$1 [NC,L]
```

Any help with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you have here? What error do you get? What have you tried to debug it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create friendly URLs with .htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the trailer `/` character from your rewrite rule. `^(.*)/$` matches any URL that ends in a `/` like `http://myapp/test/`. You are probably looking for `^(.*)$` or to strip any leading slash `^/(.*)$`. Note though that if `index.php` is accessed directly via f.ex. `http://myapp/index.php` this would also match and rewrite to `http://myapp/index.php?cat=index.php` and any images wouldn't also be directly accesible. So you might want to add some `RewriteCond` that first checks if the requested URL is an existing file with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before the `RedirectRule` to rewrite the URL.