# Host Pages Underneath One File in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Ok now I've seen this used on multiple sites but never actually seen how it is done. How do people host pages under a PHP file?

Example:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php/about
```

I've seen examples that show you how to do things like this:

```
http://www.website.com/?id=4
```

But that is not what I want to do, I want to do the top one but I have searched all over and so far I can't find anything relating to it. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated and also how would you do the HTACCESS for it to be:

```
http://www.website.com/about
```

Any and all help is appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: Just Google "friendly urls php htaccess" and you'll have everything you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create friendly URLs with .htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your raw URL needs to be strutured with a querystring like this:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php?p=about
```

And your `index.php` file has to have a handler, something like this:

```
$page_to_show = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
if ('about' === strtolower($page_to_show)) {
   show_about_page();
}
```

Finally, you'll need to be running Apache as your web server, with `mod_rewrite` installed. You'll need to add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

This will allow your script to show the `about` page if a user enters:

```
http://www.website.com/about
```