# How to convert get strings to slug?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

**Bounty Note: I've found my solution for my question using add_rewrite_rules. I will reward the bounty to anyone who can provide me with the same solution in apache RewriteRules format.**

I've read [How can I create friendly URLs with .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess) but it still difficult and complicate to me.

I am running WordPress Multisite, and I have a sub domain website cp.example.com and I'm writing a php app on this sub domain.

I have a website address that is looks like this:

```
http://cp.example.com/sales.php?id=12345&userid=123456&uid=83hkuhdqhuhd873xsuhdqwiuhdiq
```

Is it possible for me to let user access the website via:

```
http://cp.example.com/sales/12345/userid/123456/83hkuhdqhuhd873xsuhdqwiuhdiq
```

And if I were to do that will php still be able to do `$_GET` on the values?

e.g `$_GET['id']`, `$_GET['userid']` and `$_GET['uid']`?

I'm using WordPress for my base, but i'm writing the app end, using a different table.

I'm trying to avoid using custom post type just to achieve the above.

I've tried the following.

1. Create a template file view_sales.php in view_sales.php I will require `$_GET['id']`, `$_GET['userid']` and `$_GET['uid']` in order to retrieve info from mysql.
2. in `view_sales.php` I've also used a different header file and have `get_header('sales')`;
3. in header-sales.php I've added the following code gotten from the above stack overflow page.

   ```
   $path_components = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
   $id=$path_components[0];
   $userid=$path_components[1];
   $uid=$path_components[2];
   ```
4. I created a new wp page with slug sales so now the website is 
   http://cp.example.com/sales/?id=123456&userid=123456&token=98917397219372iheu1i
5. I only have one `.htacess` website in my `/public_html/example.com` domain since it's a multisite so I added the code suggested above to my `.htaccess` and now it looks like this.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

Nothing is working at the moment, still redirecting to the ugly url.

**Edited:**

I've tried the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cp\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^listing/([a-z0-9]+)$ listing/?action=$1 [L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^view/([a-z9-9]+)$ view/?id=$ [L,NC]
```

I tried different variants of all the above but nothing works.

**Edited for add_rewrite_rule method which i tried**

```
function pa_custom_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^/listing/([^/]+)/$', 'index.php?pagename=listing&action=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'pa_custom_rules');
```

Printed the rewrite array and I can see the new rule

```
      [^/listing/([^/]+)/$] => index.php?pagename=listing&action=$matches[1]
```

Visiting index.php works but going to /listing/test/ fails. It returns 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved problem which bothered me for last few days.

It appears Rewrite rules for specific domains does not work.

If you wish to change

> http://**subdomain**.example.com/listing?**action=add**(e.g. or DEL or VIEW)

of a **Wordpress MULTISITE** to

> http://**subdomain**.example.com/**add/** (e.g.or DEL or VIEW)

you have to **not only** add rewrite rules, but it's also compulsory to rewrite/add the tag to **query_var**.

You need to add the following to function or create a plugin to initiate it once.

```
function pa_custom_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('listing/(.*)$', 'index.php?pagename=listing&action=$matches[1]', 'top');
   add_rewrite_tag('%action%', '(.*)');
}
add_action('init', 'pa_custom_rules');
```

once done you will be able to access http://**subdomain**.example.com/listing/**add**

In your page (in this case, my page name is 'listing'), you will no longer get 404 error and you can get the value of "action" (in this case Add/Del/View) by using

```
    http://subdomain.example.com/listing/**add**
    $a = get_query_var('action');
    echo $a; //prints **add**
```

Note: You **cannot** get the value of **action** using $_GET like how RewriteRule works, but this should be able to get most things done.

I can keep working on wordpress and get all my customise beautiful links and throw away my last 3 days of work exploring Laravel and Symfony3. Thank God.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a website that is like this
>
> ```
>  http://cp.example.com/sales.php?id=12345&userid=123456&uid=83hkuhdqhuhd873xsuhdqwiuhdiq
> ```
>
> Is it possible for me to let user access the website via
>
> ```
>  http://cp.example.com/sales/12345/userid/123456/83hkuhdqhuhd873xsuhdqwiuhdiq
> ```

Yes, its possible, e.g.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sales/(\d+)/userid/(\d+)/([a-z0-8]+)$ sales.php?id=$1&userid=$2&uid=$3 [L,NC]
```

> And if i were to do that.. will php still be able to do $_GET on the
>   values?
>
> e.g $_GET['id'], $_GET['userid'] and $_GET['uid']

Yes, of course php will be able do that.

Comment: will that break wordpress multisite?

Comment: @Dave Teu unfortunately I don't know. It depends on how wordpress determines the name of the current site.

Comment: I read from other sites about Rewritecond so i added the following RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cp.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^listing/([a-z0-9]+)$ listing/?action=$1 [L,NC] but it keeps giving me 404 error