# htaccess to be used only in one folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just started to use .htaccess and i'm having an issue here.

Inside my public_html folder i have these files.

- index.php
- profile.php
- test.php
- .htaccess

And when i go to profile.php file i have some parameters.

http://website.com/profile.php?id=1&name=Doe

For showing better SEO links i'm trying to make it appear like this

http://website.com/1/Doe

with this rewrite condition

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

depended on this answer [(click here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

and then in my php file i get the `id` of the user so i can make the queries etc with this code

```
$path_components = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
$ctrl=$path_components[0];
```

But the thing is that if i do so every file in my folder is trying to make the `Rewrite Rule` but i want a specific file... the `profile.php` one.

EDiT 1:

So from the comment below i made this htaccess file, and regardless the mod_rewrite is enabled on my server, the link is not changing at all.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(?:/)?$ /profile.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my php file now..

```
$path_components = explode('/', $_GET['id']);
$ctrl=$path_components[0];
```

But the *link*

```
http://website.com/profile.php?id=1&name=Doe
```

is not changing at all.

Comment: You are missing a `RewriteCond`. Take a look at  the documentation of apache's rewriting module: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @arkascha i have edited my answer. Thanks for the info but still the link is not changing at all.

Comment: What _link_ are you talking about?

Comment: `http://website.com/profile.php?id=1&name=Doe`  it stays the same regardless the .htaccess file conditions @arkascha

Comment: A rewrite rule cannot change a link. It modifies an _incoming_ request, that is something that is sent after an existing link has been clicked for example. It cannot somehow magically change the world around it. If you create some link and write it somewhere, then that link is what it is.

Comment: What url are you going to and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @starkeen when i click a link with `href="http://website.com/profile.php?id=1&name=Doe" `  to show the link in the browser `http://website.com/1/Doe/`

Comment: That makes little sense. For SEO purposes you need to publish the link `http://website.com/1/Doe/`. Then, when that link is clicked, you _internally_ translate it back to the ugly form which can be processed internally. That is what rewriting is for.

Comment: @arkascha and when i put the `http://website.com/1/Doe` link on my browser, with the above htaccess file, it shows me 404 error

Comment: That means that your rewriting rule is not (yet) working. With the current `RewriteCond` it certainly will not match, since `%{REQUEST_URI}` of the _incoming_ request does not start with `/profile`, but with `/1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect your old url to the new one, put this above your existing rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /profile\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&name=(.+)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Comment: your htaccess code made my hole site to have a 500 site internal server error xD

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, try again. Yes this works only for profile.php

Comment: It doesnt rewrite the URL still :/

Comment: Ok, i have updated the code. Test this in an empty htaccess

Comment: Yes your code is correct but i have issues with `css` and `js` files that i load with `include(header.php)` files etc. You have any idea why?

Comment: This is because of header uri change Read this post for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115499/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-natsios-and-starkeen).

Comment: How can i do this for a subfolder now? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326610/main-htaccess-to-work-properly-on-other-folder

Answer (score 0):

Hello the issue is simple: you should exclude existing files/folders from rewriting process.
I would recommend to have only one index.php page where you get all the request and process in one place. Anyway your working htaccess file should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # exclude real folders/files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] - # redirect anything to index
    # for your version
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: too many errors? ur wrong. it was maybe only last line comment after piece of code. I've updated

Comment: Op wants to redirect url with query strings to a sef format (from old to new) Your example just rewrits the new url to old.