# Two page URL Rewriting without matching group

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to convert the url Category.php and Profile.php to url frindly, but only category it's working. I don't want to use any matching group !

Example :

> domain.com/category.php?id=5

and

> domain.com/profile.php?id=2

Convert to:

> domain.com/categoryname
>
> domain.com/profilename

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
#category
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)$ category.php?id=$1
#profile
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)$ profile.php?&id=$1
```

But that works only for category !

Thanks

Comment: this has been answered so manny times here :P

Comment: you have to use another matching group for profile.php like `profile/([^/.]*)` you cant use same matching group to send data to two files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create friendly URLs with .htaccess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

Comment: @Sam do you want to do it with .htacces? or with php ?

Comment: Yes, with .htacces.

Comment: With a URL like `domain.com/foo`, how can you (or the code) know if it's a category or a profile?

Comment: It's possible. I saw this option in some sites !

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)*$ ./category.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^profile/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
```

This should work.

Comment: Using `\d` (digit) as an identifier isn't what was requested. You should also explicitly state why you have modified the URLs to contain a prefix (`category`, `profile`). It _is_ needed here, but your answer doesn't tell why.

Comment: @Sam I'm sorry but i just re-read your question and i have to tell you u need to separate them by domain.com/category/12/ or domain.com/profile/34/ if you want  domain.com/12/ or domain.com/34/ to redirect to whichever that exist, please redirect all to index.php and do load on the back end using PHP. since if you do domain.com/5/ it can be both your category or profile ID