# Creating friendly URL's in Xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my non-friendly URL: `localhost/website/users/?name=UserA`

Now, i tried to create a friendly URL using .htaccess file.

This is everything in my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /movies/error404.html  #For Error 404

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /website/users/(.*)$ /website/users/name=$1
```

Now, When I open `localhost/website/users/UserA` it opens error 404 page.

Yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: `RewriteRule /website/users/(.*)$ /website/users/?name=$1` try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create friendly URLs with .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033407/how-can-i-create-friendly-urls-with-htaccess)

Comment: Here is the complete guide you can learn it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: Not working @FahadKazmi bro

Comment: If your non-friendly URL is working (I'm surprised) then either the rewrite rule needs to issue a redirect (put ` [R]` at the end of the rule), in which case the browser will still show the non-friendly URL after visiting the friendly one.  Otherwise the second argument in the RewriteRule should be relative to the .htaccess file's location, and look more 'internal' e.g. `RewriteRule /website/users/(.*)$ website/users.php?name=$1` (I don't have enough information to give a 100% working example, I'm just explaining)

Comment: `RewriteRule    ^website/users/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$    website/users/index.php?id=$1    [NC,L] ` try this one

Comment: Still not working @FahadKazmi http://prntscr.com/fhaw75

Comment: Still not working @FahadKazmi

Comment: It is not working may be because of `ErrorDocument`

Comment: I tried to remove Error Document, still not working bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `.htaccess` file

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^users/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$    users/index.php?name=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/movies/error404.html
```

In this cause the `.htaccess` file would be placed under the `website` directory root

**Note:** The requests are going to `index.php` file which is under the `users` directory if you have another *filename* then replace it with that one

Comment: Still not working, it redirects to error404.html 

Note: I have the .htaccess file placed inside website folder, is that right?

Comment: Still not working bro, give me 5 minutes, i will cut down some files, make a zip with only required things, and upload it.

Comment: Ok, i will see it

Comment: And When i use my previous code, which i mentioned in the question: I get this error, while opening any page http://prntscr.com/fhbq0g

Comment: Anyway, this one works perfectly fine. But it redirects me to error-404 page: If the url has space or "-", any solution for that?

Thanks a lot for helping me, really mean a lot to me

Comment: The third line for rewrite rule using regex `0-9A-Za-z` you can change it for what you want to except in url